# Add ssh key password to gnome keyring

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring

Currently I have to unlock may ssh key each session. How can I add ssh key password to my default gnome keyring?

Comment: Are you trying to log into a host through ssh without having to type in your password each time?

Comment: I am using a ssh key, not a password to login to the remote server. But the ssh key is password protected. And I would like to put that password into gnome keyring, so it is unlocked automatically when the keyring is unlocked.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I believe that you would import it into the GNOME2 Keyring.  Unlock the GNOME2 Key Storage, then do File -> Import and put in your ssh rsa file.

Comment: ehm, how? :) you can post it as an answer too

Comment: related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168062/

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have `AddKeysToAgent yes` option in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Then if you have `gnome-keyring-daemon` and its `ssh-agent` running (and pointed to appropriate socket: the same as SSH_AUTH_SOCK env) then it should ask you "graphically" for passphrase at first use. There should also be a checkbox allowing you to "Automatically unlock this key whenever I'm logged in", which stores the passphrase in the "login" keyring and is exactly what you want. If it doesn't ask for unlocking passphrase with graphical requester, chances are that

```
$ ps ax | grep keyring
```

will show you that daemon or agent is not running. You can check if the agent is enabled in `Startup Applications`. On my machine it shows "SSH Key Agent" with description "GNOME Keyring: SSH Agent".

Comment: This does not seem to work in Ubuntu 22.04. No GUI prompt for password when ssh-ing with `AddKeysToAgent yes` or when using `ssh-add`, just CLI prompt, and nothing is stored in the Gnome Keyring, just ssh-agent which requires re-entering the password on each first use. Both gnome-keyring-daemon and its ssh-agent are running and pointing to $SSH_AUTH_SOCK which is `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`.

Comment: I can't comment on the current Ubuntu versions. 18.10 was my last. Then, after many, many years I eventually ditched Ubuntu. Even if I tried hard to adapt myself to gnome before doing this…

Comment: For me the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` changed to `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh`
suddenly

```
ps ax | grep keyring
   2646 ?        SLl    0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11
   9209 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
```